# Error starting Spring boot application with ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I want to use ElasticSearch with Spring Data. I am using Spring 5, Spring Boot 2 and ElasticSearch 7.4. Docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: "elasticsearch"
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
    expose:
      - 9200
      - 9300
    environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - elastic
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.2
    container_name: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
    ports:
    - 5601:5601
    networks:
      - elastic
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {

}

@Data
@Document(indexName = "fias", type = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String fullAddress;
}
```

Config:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class Config {
    @Bean
    RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration configuration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();
        return RestClients.create(configuration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
}
```

And error when starting application:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)V

The error occurs in the Config::*elasticsearchClient* method on the line: **.build();**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    @Bean
    RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")
        ));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
}
```

maven (maybe some dependencies can be removed):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```